# How to prevent pluralization of a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have model called `Search` and a resource named `:search`. I'd like to name my controller `SearchController`, rather than `SearchesController`. But when I initialize an instance of Search, Rails assumes its route has to be "/searches".

Is there anything I can do to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`resources :search, :as => :searches`

Route urls start with `/search`, point to `search` controller and use default naming convention:

```
   searches GET    /search(.:format)          {:controller=>"search", :action=>"index"}
            POST   /search(.:format)          {:controller=>"search", :action=>"create"}
 new_search GET    /search/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"search", :action=>"new"}
edit_search GET    /search/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"search", :action=>"edit"}
     search GET    /search/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"search", :action=>"show"}
            PUT    /search/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"search", :action=>"update"}
            DELETE /search/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"search", :action=>"destroy"}
```

The reason for error is that when form has only access to model instance it tries to find a route helper based on pluralized model name. In this case it tried to use `searches_path`. Things should work if we keep the default route names and change only urls and controller.

[Relevant documentation](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M006524) (under "Relying on named routes")

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in my routes file. Problem is it doesn't work. The instance of Search passed to a form fails due to "no route '/searches' found."